# What's the correct variant

Tags: grammaticality

I'm making slides for my colleagues that summarize some of my experience in our domain. The team is international and I am not a native English speaker.

One of the slides should contain ten tips a about processing speedup. And processing is a noun here — it means the act of transforming the information.

How do I say that correctly in English:

- 10 Tips for Speedup Processing
- 10 Tips for Processing Speedup
- 10 Tips for Speedup the Processing

???

Comment: I cannot. "Processing" here is the act of transforming one data into another format. I need to save this semantics.

Comment: "speedup processing" implies that it's the processing step(s) that's being sped up.  "Processing speedup" implies an over all speed increase.  In all cases I'd change the lead in to read "10 Tips To Speed Up processing" with those two changes.  (I find "speedup" as a noun, where "speed up" is a verb)

Comment: @Cascabel, I guess both are nouns, not verbs

Comment: Please add what you've clarified in comments into the question itself. If both words *are* meant to be nouns, then there is only one correct answer. (And it's none of the three currently given, because they all assume that at least one of the words is meant to be taken as a verb.) But add it as a note so that it doesn't invalidate the existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

The correct choice out of the three is

> 10 Tips for Processing Speedup

In this construction, the **speedup** is what the tips are for and **processing** is what the speedup affects.

As mentioned in Patrick Hughes's answer, "10 Tips To Speed Up Processing" is another option, it's equivalent in meaning to the one above.

As for the other two:

> 10 Tips for Speedup Processing

would mean that the tips are for processing of the speedup, and while grammatically correct it's not what you mean.

> 10 Tips for Speedup the Processing

is grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You say you are trying to speed up some data processing.

It is common in IT to use what are normally verbs as nouns and to use nouns as if they were adjectives.

There are, however, problems with your options.

> 1. 10 tips for processing speedup could either be *10 tips for processing a speedup* or it could be read as *10 tips for speeding up processing*.  As I understand you, it is this latter meaning you are trying to convey.
> 2. “10 tips for speedup processing” reads to me as meaning  that you are trying to process speedup. So that will not do.
> 3. “10 tips for speedup the processing” is grammatically incorrect.  The word *for* in this context demands the noun phrase ‘*speeding up*

But 3 is your best option, if you correct it in the way I suggest.

By the way, your English is mostly good.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above. The correct way to convey what you want is

> Ten tips to speed up prices-sing